# Statergies for simulating a hierarchical network using sparsification approaches but mainting global trends

Tags: r, simulation, graph-theory

**TLDR:**
I am trying to simulate a hierarchical network using DFS as a way to sparsify the network. This works to link nodes using edges within the DFS but interactions between nodes are lost. Aside for switching out DFS for something like backbone analysis are there fields of research/papers that address similar issues that I can get some ideas from?

**Background:**
We are trying to simulate bulk RNAseq data for protein-coding genes using protein-protein interaction data to model the interactions between different genes. Each gene has its own distribution (typically negative binomial) and we are using correlations between gene counts as a basis for linking the expression of genes together. E.g. Gene A - Gene B strong correlation, so in sample 1 if A is high B should also be high but in sample 2 if A is low then so should B.

**Problem:**
We have used a DFS-type strategy to simplify the network and generated counts sequentially (~250K edges -> 16K edges). This has worked as expected i.e. in the simulated data the correlation between genes linked by the DFS tends to agree with each other. The problem is that correlations between genes not captured in the search are lost and if you examine cliques within the PPI network there is no overall correlation between observed and simulated interactions.

**Type of help I need:**
Doing a quick literature search I found that I should be using something like backbone (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/backbone/vignettes/backbone.html) instead of a DFS. However, this will only solve a minor problem. Can anyone point me in the direction of some graph theory, other types of theory or papers that are related to this problem, please?

**Limitations:**
I might have access to a server to crunch some numbers but most of this analysis will be run on a cheap laptop and I am using R.